# Why there is argv[i][0], whenever I try to do some operation using operator in command line argument in c?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am learning command line argument in C. There is a section where I am supposed to define the char variable with a position of argv[i] . I tried using `argv[2]`, but it showing some warning `( warning: initialization of 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] )`

whenever, I did `argv[2][0]`, it did worked.

Why there is a 0 in the end. It seemed like a 2d array for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc,  char *argv[])
{
    int a, b, sum = 0 ;
    char operate = argv[2][0] ; //I tried running it by using argv[2], but it showing a conversion error
    // warning: initialization of 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion].

    if(argv[4])
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid numebr ") ;
        return -1 ;
    }
    a = atoi(argv[1]) ;
    b = atoi(argv[3]) ;

    //now to choose operator
    switch(operate) {
        case '+' :
            sum = a + b;
            break;

        case '-' :
            sum = a - b;
            break;
    }

    printf("The operation is = %d", sum ) ;
}
```

Comment: The command line arguments are an array of pointers to strings, and each string is a null-terminated array, so the argument list is similar to a ragged 2D array (because the arguments are not necessarily all the same length).  That's why using `argv[i][0]` produces a `char` value (assuming `i < argc`).

Comment: You should be checking `if (argc != 4) { fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s number ± number\n", argv[0]); return 1; }` or similar to enforce 3 arguments.  Your `switch` should have a `default` clause to report unrecognized operators.  You should probably check that there is no other character in `argv[2]` (so the user didn't run `./prog 23 -= 14`).  Using `atoi()` is a little sloppy — it will produce zero even if the user types `one` as the argument.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler has explained very nicely, you can also try this to cast as char pointer like this try your self and see.
`char *operator = (char *) argv[2];`

Comment: @Hackaholic no cast is required, nor advised, for that initialization. It is superfluous. More text != more better.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you for the information, I was just being verbose for the OP to get some understanding.

Answer (score 7):

> The argv argument is a vector of C strings; its elements are the
> individual command line argument strings. The file name of the program
> being run is also included in the vector as the first element; the
> value of argc counts this element. A null pointer always follows the
> last element: argv[argc] is this null pointer.

```
char operate = argv[2][0] ;
```

Here, `argv[2]` is a null-terminated array of characters, or a `char *`. The type of `operate` is `char`. You're trying to initialize a `char` with a `char *`, hence the warning.

`argv[2][0]` means the first element of the the `char *` which is a `char`. So the definition is valid, and you get no warnings.

```
argv[2] ---> Apple 
             |
             | 
         argv[2][0]
```

The above answer assumes that `i < argc`.
Before accessing an argument, you should check whether it is valid or not.